# Not able to connect to TFS 2008 and TFS 2010 from visual studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, tfs

VS 2010 was already installed on my machine and able to connect to both TFS 2008 and TFS 2010 server. Now I need to use VS2008 and need to connect to TFS 2010. 
I followed the following sequence to installed and update the VS2008 but not able to connect to the TFS 2008 and 2010 both server.

1. install Visual Studio 2008
2. Install VS 2008 Team Explorer
3. re-install VS 2008 Service Pack 1
4. install the Visual Studio Team System 2008 Service Pack 1 Forward
   Compatibility Update for Team Foundation Server 2010
   (VS90SP1-KB974558-x86.exe)

getting same error message "TF31002: Unable to connect to this Team Foundation Server [Servername]..."

Answer (score 2):

You've got all the software, to connect to TFS 2010 you need to use the full url e.g. `http://servername:8080/tfs/collection`

Comment: I have the same problem - the add server does not have a option to specify /tfs. All I can do is to enter server name and port and no option for subfolders and when I try to enter server/tfs - it gives me formatting error

Comment: @ IMHO If everthing is installed correctly then you need to put the full url in the server name box, this will grey out the port number box. If you still have the problem you must install the software in the correct order. VS 2008, Team explorer, SP1, forward compatability update. This will allow you to add the http:// at the beginning and the /tfs/collection at the end of the server name. If you think you have everything installed then remove the forward compatability update, re apply SP1 and then re install the forward comapatability update.